# Is there a way for a simple way for ClassLibrary to get Session Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I have an external ClassLibrary Project that needs to get session value set from HomeController in the Main Project.
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Or is there an alternative to transfer a value from HomeController to an external ClassLibrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IHttpContextAccessor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

> For other framework and custom components that require access to
>   HttpContext, the recommended approach is to register a dependency
>   using the built-in dependency injection container. The dependency
>   injection container supplies the IHttpContextAccessor to any classes
>   that declare it as a dependency in their constructors.
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>      services.AddMvc()
>          .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
>      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
>      services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(); 
> }
> ```
>
> In the following example:
>
> - UserRepository declares its dependency on IHttpContextAccessor.
> - The dependency is supplied when dependency injection resolves the dependency chain and creates an instance of UserRepository.
>
> .
>
> ```
> public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
> {
>     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
>
>     public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
>     {
>         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
>     }
>
>     public void LogCurrentUser()
>     {
>         var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
>         service.LogAccessRequest(username);
>     }
> }
> ```

Don't forget to add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to make the dependency injection work.

Comment: Is there a way to directly reference httpcontext without injecting it to the class constructor? A View page references the class library method directly which will clash with the httpcontext injection.

Answer (score 2):

The single-responsibility principle dictates that a class should do just one thing. While you can inject something like `IHttpContextAccessor` that then requires the class to have knowledge of concepts like `HttpContext`, `Session`, the fact that it's being used in a web environment in the first place, etc.

The correct approach is to inject or pass *values*. If the class needs a particular value from a session variable, access the session in your controller, where that logic actually belongs, and then pass only the value from the session to your external class.

Answer (score -1):

If u use Abp template, the Abp application service `ApplicationService` already contains property `AbpSession`, you can inherit this class.

Comment: Recommending someone use an alternate library is not an answer. And, boilerplate isn't even a good recommendation. It's a solution in search of a problem. It might have made some amount of sense back in the ASP.NET MVC version, but it's completely superfluous with Core.